# Verification for the validity of example for perfect sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I have been studying Basic Topology (Chapter 2) from Baby Rudin when I read about the definition of the perfect sets.

> $E$ is a perfect set if $E$ is closed (every limiting point of $E$ belongs to $E$), and every point of $E$ is a limiting point of $E$.

Now to properly understand this statement, I constructed an example for myself which is as follows:

***The Example:***

Let $E=[2,3]\cup\{5\}$

Now observe that $5$ is not a limiting point for $E$ as $\nexists q\in N_1(5): q\in E\space$ $(N_1(5)\space \text{is the neighbourhood of 5 with radius 1})$. But every point in $[2,3]$ is a limiting point of $E$.

Thus here, every limiting point of $E$ belong to $E$, hence it is closed *(I'm not very sure about this statement, but I think it should be correct according to the definition)*. But every point of $E$ is not a limiting point of $E$ ($5\in E$, but $5$ is not a limiting point of $E$).

$\therefore\space E$ is not perfect set.

Let $E=(2,3)$

Observe that every point of $E$, along with $2$ and $3$, is a limiting point of $E$. But $2\notin E$ and $3\notin E$.

Thus here, every point of $E$ is limiting point of $E$, but every limiting point $E$ is not in $E$.

$\therefore\space E$ is not a perfect set.

If $E=[2,3]$, then $E$ is a perfect set.

I wanted to verify the validity of this example. That is, I wanted to know if this example encapsulated the concept of perfect sets correctly enough or not. Please tell if there are any mistakes.

***THANK YOU***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples are correct: $[2,3]\cup \{5\}$ is closed but has an isolated point and $(2,3)$ has only limit points but does not contain all of them, so is indeed not closed. Of course $\Bbb R$ and $[0,1]$ are positive examples that do fulfil the conditions (as does the Cantor middle third set that Rudin also discusses).